# reshape dataframe based on string values

Tags: string, r, reshape2

I want to melt a dataframe into long format based on the unique values in a string variable. Some example data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(lllocatie = structure(c(3L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 22L, 4L, 36L, 37L, 31L, 15L, 23L, 20L, 34L, 8L, 35L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 2L, 29L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 8L, 22L, 9L, 20L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 38L, 6L, 27L, 7L, 11L, 17L, 33L, 14L, 2L, 21L, 18L, 9L, 28L, 32L, 1L), .Label = c("Annen", "Appingedam", "Assen", "Eleveld", "Emmen", "Farmsum", "Froombosch", "Garrelsweer", "Garsthuizen", "Geelbroek", "Hellum", "Hoogezand", "Hooghalen", "Huizinge", "Langelo", "Leermens", "Meedhuizen", "Onderdendam", "Oosterwijtwerd", "Overschild", "Roodeschool", "Roswinkel", "Sappemeer", "Sint Annen", "Slochteren", "Startenhuizen", "Steendam", "Stitswerd", "t-Zandt", "Ten Post", "Tjuchem", "Toornwerd", "Tripscompagnie", "Westerbroek", "Westerwijtwerd", "Winneweer", "Woudbloem", "Zandeweer"), class = "factor"), lat = c(52.992, 52.928, 52.771, 52.952, 52.965, 53.358, 52.953, 52.956, 52.831, 52.961, 53.32, 53.21, 53.294, 53.084, 53.16, 53.285, 53.177, 53.305, 53.316, 53.315, 53.333, 53.336, 53.332, 53.363, 53.368, 53.208, 53.202, 53.294, 53.306, 52.833, 53.37, 53.279, 53.323, 53.17, 53.345, 53.39, 53.316, 53.275, 53.194, 53.226, 53.294, 53.156, 53.359, 53.335, 53.423, 53.324, 53.372, 53.365, 53.351, 53.061), lon = c(6.548, 6.552, 6.914, 6.575, 6.573, 6.657, 6.572, 6.562, 7.032, 6.57, 6.74, 6.747, 6.868, 6.465, 6.805, 6.795, 6.685, 6.793, 6.65, 6.66, 6.837, 6.808, 6.848, 6.765, 6.675, 6.812, 6.82, 6.753, 6.777, 7.045, 6.72, 6.807, 6.805, 6.747, 6.808, 6.68, 6.962, 6.828, 6.798, 6.835, 6.95, 6.823, 6.682, 6.852, 6.77, 6.613, 6.743, 6.577, 6.628, 6.698), mag.cat = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), names = structure(c(3L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 21L, 29L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 24L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 23L, 1L, 27L, 12L, 1L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 10L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 14L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 22L, 7L, 13L, 26L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("", "Amen,Assen,Deurze,Ekehaar,Eleveld,Geelbroek,Hooghalen,Marwijksoord,Vredenheim", "Amen,Assen,Deurze,Ekehaar,Eleveld,Geelbroek,Taarlo,Ubbena", "Amen,Ekehaar,Eleveld,Geelbroek,Hooghalen", "Annen,Gasteren,Nieuw Annerveen,Oud Annerveen,Schipborg,Zeegse,Zuidlaren","Bedum,Eppenhuizen,Garsthuizen,Huizinge,Kantens,Middelstum,Onderdendam,Rottum,Sint Annen,Startenhuizen,Stedum,Stitswerd,Tinallinge,Toornwerd,Uithuizen,Usquert,Warffum,Westeremden,Westerwijtwerd,Zandeweer", "Bedum,Huizinge,Kantens,Lellens,Middelstum,Onderdendam,Rottum,Sauwerd,Sint Annen,Stedum,Stitswerd,Thesinge,Tinallinge,Toornwerd,Westeremden,Westerwijtwerd,Wetsinge,Winsum", "Eleveld,Geelbroek", "Emmen", "Emmer-Compascuum,Roswinkel", "Eppenhuizen,Garsthuizen,Huizinge,Kantens,Middelstum,Oldenzijl,Onderdendam,Rottum,Startenhuizen,Stedum,Stitswerd,Toornwerd,Uithuizen,Westeremden,Westerwijtwerd,Zandeweer","Eppenhuizen,Garsthuizen,Huizinge,Kantens,Middelstum,Oldenzijl,Rottum,Startenhuizen,Toornwerd,Westeremden,Zandeweer", "Eppenhuizen,Garsthuizen,Oldenzijl,Startenhuizen,t-Zandt,Westeremden,Zeerijp,Zijldijk", "Eppenhuizen,Oldenzijl,Startenhuizen,Uithuizen,Zandeweer", "Froombosch,Hellum,Noordbroek,Sappemeer,Schildwolde,Slochteren", "Garrelsweer", "Garrelsweer,Overschild,Ten Post,Winneweer", "Huizinge,Startenhuizen", "Langelo", "Leermens,Oosterwijtwerd", "Loppersum,Winneweer", "Oosteinde,Roodeschool", "Oosterwijtwerd", "Overschild", "Steendam", "Stitswerd", "t-Zandt,Zeerijp", "Westerbroek", "Woudbloem"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("lllocatie", "lat", "lon", "mag.cat", "names"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

The observations where the `names` column is empty, need to be excluded from the new dataframe. When you look for example at the first row:

```
lllocatie    lat   lon mag.cat                                                     names
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3 Amen,Assen,Deurze,Ekehaar,Eleveld,Geelbroek,Taarlo,Ubbena
```

In the reshaped dataframe this row should result in the following desired output:

```
lllocatie    lat   lon mag.cat     names
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3      Amen
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3     Assen
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Deurze
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3   Ekehaar
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3   Eleveld
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3 Geelbroek
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Taarlo
    Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Ubbena
```

The observations where the `names` column is empty, need to be excluded from the reshaped dataframe. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is a kind of geocoded data. Your melted dataframe will have a lat, long and mag.cat for each location? for a single row, all places will have shaded coordinates. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Henrik That does indeed give an answer to my question. On the other hand, the answer of jlhoward gives a nice alternative solution. As jlhoward's approach is easier to understand, I think this question & answer is a valuable addition to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df1)
result <- dt[,strsplit(as.character(names),",",fixed=T),
              by=list(lllocatie,lat,lon,mag.cat)]
head(result,10)
#     lllocatie    lat   lon mag.cat        V1
#  1:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3      Amen
#  2:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3     Assen
#  3:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Deurze
#  4:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3   Ekehaar
#  5:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3   Eleveld
#  6:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3 Geelbroek
#  7:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Taarlo
#  8:     Assen 52.992 6.548       3    Ubbena
#  9: Hooghalen 52.928 6.552       3      Amen
# 10: Hooghalen 52.928 6.552       3   Ekehaar
```

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it describes what I want to achieve better now.

Comment: I edited my response. Compliments to @BrodieG for making me aware of this really neat feature of data.tables.